# calling function based on dom change

Tags: jquery, dom, onchange

I rewrote a bit of my code based on that it's not really feasible to check to see if a javascript variable changes. But, how would I do it with a dom element? For instance

```
<div id='foo'>123</div>
<script>
$('#foo').html('456');
// function gets fired since #foo changed.
</script>
```

I tried

```
$("#foo").change(function () {
      alert('change!');
    })
    .change();
```

but no luck.

Answer (score 3):

See:

- [Detect div content changes with
  jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091661/detect-div-content-changes-with-jquery)
- [Custom events in jQuery open doors
  to complex behaviors](http://www.reynoldsftw.com/2009/04/custom-events-in-jquery-open-doors-to-complex-behaviors/)

Comment: Hello from the future. Your second link is broken.