# How to detect changes to a table using JQuery

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a table which always updates by clicking on another link. This link has ajax functionality which is created by serverside API at run time and JQuery has no control over this link. 
Now whenever this link changes table, I want to call a function by JQuery, how do I do that?

Comment: Someone wrote a plug-in that sounds like it might be exactly what you need. Check out the accepted answer on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233991/jquery-watch-div/3234646#3234646