# Listen to creation, change and deletion events in jQuery

Tags: jquery, callback

I am trying to call a function everytime a `.element` is created or deleted, or when the content of a `.element` changed. I can use [livequery](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery) for the creation event; is there a way to register "edit" or "delete" callbacks?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`livequery` can handle the deletion of the element. Pass a second function argument. It will run when an element that matches the selector is removed.

With respect to edit, I suppose it will depend on the type of edit. If you remove a class such that it no longer matches the selector you gave to `livequery`, I think the second function argument will be triggered in that case as well.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. About the change event, this is what I need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233991/jquery-watch-div/3234646#3234646