# Does replacing the content of a span raise an event?

Tags: jquery

If I replace the content of a span using the syntax below, does it raise an event?:

```
$("#container").html(data);
```

I am trying to refresh another div whenever the content of #container changes, but I don't know which #container event to bind.  I am using jQuery.

Any assistance appreciated.

UPDATE:  Here is a more comprehensive code listing...

```
$.post(addUri, myForm.serialize(), function(data) {
       $("#container").html(data);
   }, 'html');
```

Comment: Why can't you refresh the div everytime you insert something into `#container`? Is `#container` mutated by an external script?

Comment: I have updated with a more comprehensive code listing.  Basically, if I call my refresh function after the post, the span has not had time to update.  I could make the post synchronous, but I don't really want to do that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a built-in listener for content changes in a span, so you could create your own:

```
$('#container').bind('contentchanged', function() {
  alert('the content of my container changed!');
});
```

and trigger it like this:

```
$("#container").html(data).trigger('contentchanged');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) to trigger a custom event and listen for that with [.bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/).

Answer (score 0):

jQuery doesn't provide the functionality to track changes to content. Someone has written a plug-in to do what you need in the answers to this question - [jQuery watch div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233991/jquery-watch-div/3234646#3234646)