# Detect change in div and do rebind events jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, html

In jQuery how can I watch a div to determine if it has changed so that I can rebind events and perform some other action as needed?

Comment: What do you mean with "changed"? And why do you have to rebind events then?

Comment: Change as in elements are appended\removed from it

Comment: why don't you use a function after appending/removing?

Comment: because a class appends and removes.  I found the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233991/jquery-watch-div

Answer (score 1):

If the `div` has dynamic content I would like to tell you about [event delegation](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate).

> Event delegation allows you to avoid adding event listeners to
>   specific nodes;  instead, the event listener is added to one parent.[1](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate)

To use event delegation in jQuery you use the [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method *and* provide a `selector` argument.

Comment: Event delegation is a great solution for using events with dynamic content.

Comment: Thank you Tim. "Dynamic content" was the concept I was searching for. Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use DOMSubtreeModified event(see [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Events-20001113/events.html#Events-MutationEvent))

```
$('my-selector').bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function() {
  console.log('Children have been modified');
});
```

I haven't checked the supported nature of this event but in chrome it works.

Unfortunately : [Why is the DOMSubtreeModified event deprecated in DOM level 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659662/why-is-the-domsubtreemodified-event-deprecated-in-dom-level-3)