# jquery set div from mysql then alert for changes

Tags: jquery, mysql, html

Im getting a row count from Mysql using php and i have a jquery refresh which loads the rowcount into the div and displays it.
this works great!

Now i need to send an alert if the div's value changes.
Ive tried the code below, but it doesnt detect any changes with the div.
Any ideas?

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
    $('#load_tweets').load('<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/login/count_users/');
}, 1000);

$('#load_tweets').change( function() {
notify('NEW JOB');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery .change() method works only for form fields.

You can look at below answer on SO for alternative :

[jQuery watch div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233991/jquery-watch-div/3234646#3234646)