# jquery 1.7+ , body append a new element , and how to bind action to it with on() rather than live()?

Tags: jquery

I used live function before jquery 1.6.
In jquery 1.7+, live function is not recommended, but using on function.
I have a question with follow code:

```
        $('#button').on('click', function(event) {
                    //add a new element to body
                    $('body').append('<div class="future">I am a new div</div>');
        });
    //bind a action to new element which is add a moment ago.
    $('body').on('change', '.future', function() {
        $(this).css({
            'color' : 'red',
            'font-weight' : 'bold'
        });
        $(this).text("on click me.");
        $(this).on('click', {
            name : 'liujun'
        }, myhandler);
    });

    function myhandler(event) {
        alert(event.data.name);
    }
```

new action is not working,and syntax is correct. why?

Comment: replace `$(this).on('click',` with `$(this).bind('click',` or `$(this).click(,` 
------
`{
            name : 'liujun'
        }` 
not looks like selector

Comment: `<div>` elements do not emit `change` events. Do you want to handle `change` events triggered on a descendant of the `<div>`? If that's the case, then the second argument to `on()` should match that element.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi hiya bruv `:)` howz life? I reckon you can - he/she OP is looking for something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979738/fire-jquery-event-on-div-change

Comment: I have also the same problem `live` but `on` is not working

Answer (score 2):

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/nQDs2/4/

- first click `button` the try clicking `trigger`
- Then, click on the red `on click me` message.

[Fire jQuery event on div change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979738/fire-jquery-event-on-div-change)\

For **IE** [jQuery watch div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233991/jquery-watch-div/3234646#3234646)

I am not sure why I am getting down voted, hope it fits your cause `:)`

**code**

```
$('#button').on('click', function(event) {
    //add a new element to body
    $('body').append('<div class="future">I am a new div</div>');
});


//bind a action to new element which is add a moment ago.
$('body').on('change', '.future', function() {
    $(this).css({
        'color': 'red',
        'font-weight': 'bold'
    });
    $(this).text("on click me.");
    $(this).on('click', {
        name: 'liujun'
    }, myhandler);
}).bind('DOMNodeInserted DOMNodeRemoved', function(event) {
    if (event.type == 'DOMNodeInserted') {
       // alert('Content added! Current content:' + '\n\n' + this.innerHTML);
    } else {
       // alert('Content removed! Current content:' + '\n\n' + this.innerHTML);
    };
});

$('#trgbutton').click(function() {
    $('.future').trigger('change');
});

function myhandler(event) {
    alert(event.data.name);
}​
```

Comment: Downvote why? please comment `:)` C'mon! This is not right! and demotivating at times!

Comment: Absolutely agree with you. Downvoters: please add explanation before downvoting. You are doing nothing but miss-using your reputation

Comment: I did not downvote, but maybe it's due to the DOM mutation events not being supported by all browsers (notably Internet Explorer).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi *Solution for IE:* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233991/jquery-watch-div/3234646#3234646 `:))` this is demotivating when people down vote anyhooo~

Comment: @Tats_innit i think you get downvote because this is not the correct solution of OP question?

Comment: Upvoted to bypass downvoters. I know the feeling: downvoters without leaving a comment. Annoying and demotivating indeed.

Comment: Hiya @jhonraymos Thanks bruv, If you will play around with my demo you will see it is working `:)` OP issue was triggering the `change event!

Comment: @BramVanroy Thanks heaps bruv! I will neither forget your deed and this shall be returned `:)` cheers!

Comment: @Dipaks Thanks bruv! for support!

Comment: @Tats_innit i know it is working but ..It is not the exact solution

Comment: @jhonraymos how do you mean bruv? `:)` did I missed anything? let me know! if you will play around with my demo you will see that I fixed OPs new action as well `:)`

Comment: @Tats_innit i have the same problem `live` works but `on ` function is not working.Because `<div>` is added after page load? I think this isn't the best approach for that?

Comment: @jhonraymos Cool man `:)` bruv in OPs case its the change eveny on `div` flick me your issue will try to fix it - but in this case - if you see my demo - **1)** click on button **2)**  click trigger, to trigger change event on `div` **3)** now click on red tex on the div and the `myHnadler` event will get fire.. Although flick me your issue I will try to help you out `:)`

Comment: @jhonraymos all good bruv! Thanks to you as well `:)` Anytime! if you want feel free to flick me the issue I will take a look `:)`

Comment: function myhandler(event) {
    alert(event.data.name);
}​

this function is not call when I click new element. but how?

Comment: hiya @君主不是我 `:)` http://jsfiddle.net/nQDs2/5/ - **step 1)** click on button **step 2)** click on trigger button final **Step 3** click on the red text and you will see your alert getting called! `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Im pretty sure this piece of code is the culprit.

```
$(this).on('click', {
      name : 'liujun'
}, myhandler);
```

It doesn't look like a valid syntax.

If you want to pass a parameter, try this

```
   $(this).on("click", function(e) {
      myHandler({name: liujun})
   })
```

It's actually pretty confusing, if you could show us the HTML in jsFiddle maybe we could help more.