# jQuery event on (dynamic) table row change

Tags: jquery, jsp, events

So I've been trying to monitor when my dynamic table changes in rows and tbody's.. here's an example of the structure:

```
<table id="assignedTable"> 
    <tbody class="assigned"> 
        <tr id="#uniquenumberhere">
        </tr> 
        <tr>
        </tr> 
    </tbody> 
</table>
```

This is what I got so far.. but it doesn't work:

```
$(function(){
            $('#assignedTable').on('change', '.assigned', function(){
                $('#assignableTbody').append("dynamic table changed");
            });
        })
```

Hope anyone can help, 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might find this answer useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233991/jquery-watch-div/3234646#3234646

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use a change event on a table. Check out the jquery documentation

> The change event is sent to an element when its value changes. This event is limited to  elements,  boxes and  elements. For select boxes,

[Jquery Documentation on the change event](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

Perhaps you can try polling the table and count the table rows and see if that value changes, but this isn't good for performance.

Comment: Alright.. missed that much, thanks for your answer! I'll think of a different solution

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite your table to divs or other tags, create css rules for them to design them as you like and you will be able to define a change event handler for your "root" div.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread, but I had never needed to do this before but it is fairly simple by creating a function that you call when a row gets selected.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brockangelo/ozycan94/)

```
var checkButton = function() {
    if ($('tr.selected').length > 0) {
        $('#analyze').prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
        $('#analyze').prop('disabled', true);
    }
}
$('#table tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    checkButton();
});
```