# Changing text when unrelated divs are empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the div `event_wrapper` that can be dynamically added on a page by clicking the link in `add-event`. The user can delete/add these divs as many times as they want. If the user chooses to delete all of these `event_wrapper` divs, I want to change the text inside `add-event`. Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="event_wrapper">
    <div class="event">
        <div class="well darkblue-background pull-left">
            <a class="close tooltip" data-tooltip="Delete this event"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="add-event pull-left">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);"> And Then...</a>
   </div>
```

(I am using jQuery) I tried using `:empty` selector, but it does not seem to be working. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: please give some code samples. If you want change text inside add-event $(".add-event").children('a').html("Your text");

Comment: are you wanting to check if there is the event_wrapper div or divs inseide the event_wrapper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at - https://stackoverflow.com/a/3234646/295852

And then use `contentChange()` like:

```
$('.event-wrapper').contentChange(function(){
    if($(this).children().length > 0){
        // events exist
        $(".add-event pull-left").children('a').html('And Then...');
    } else {
        // no events
        $(".add-event pull-left").children('a').html('your text');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!$(".event_wrapper")){
    $(".add-event pull-left").html("Whatever text you want here"); //changes the text of the div
     //or
    $(".add-event pull-left").children('a').html("whatever text you want here"); //changes the text of the anchor child
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  if($(".event-wrapper").html() == null) {//looking inside event-wrapper; if it contains any thing
    $(".add-event a").html("whatever");
  }
```