# Check if content in DIV has changed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm loading some content inside a div with `setInterval`, and I don't want it to run everytime so I need to check if the content has changed from the last time it ran.

**Here's what I'm currently using that's not working**

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function() {
    $('#loaddiv').load('/wzha/reload.php');
    $('#loaddiv').change(function() {
        var dddd = $('#loaddiv').text();
        alert(dddd);
    });
}, 1000);
```

**Example:**

reload.php is just `<?php echo 'something here'; ?>`. When I save reload.php, it needs to put `something here` in to the `#loaddiv`. It should not load the div anymore until I re-save reload.php to something else.

Comment: Not sure I get this, changed how, and only form elements, like inputs, have a change event ?

Comment: are you changing this locally, or wanting to see if the data on the server's changed?

Comment: reload.php is just `<?php echo 'something here'; ?>`. When I save reload.php, it needs to put `something here` in to the `#loaddiv`. It should not load the div anymore until I re-save reload.php to something else.

Comment: Why don't you save the contents of reload.php as a variable, and every time you call the function, check to see if the old variable matches the new one. If they are the same then don't update, if they are different, then you can update

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233991/jquery-watch-div or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091661/detect-element-content-changes-with-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like :

```
var content,
    auto_refresh = setInterval(function() {
        $.get('/wzha/reload.php&r=' + (new Date()).getTime(), function(data) {
            if (data != content) {
                content = data;
                $('#loaddiv').html(data);
            }
        });
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Didn't work bro. I see what you are doing, and I thought it would work, but it didn't even load the div.

Comment: @ChristianDaley - changed it a little bit, should work like that ?