# is it possible to register live() an ajaxForm()?

Tags: jquery, jquery-forms-plugin

I'm doing like this:

```
$('.myforms').ajaxForm();
```

after I add some more forms to the html which have this `.myforms` class assigned, so I have to call the `$('.myforms').ajaxForm()` **again**

is it possible to register the ajaxForm live ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

checkout the [Live Query plugin](http://brandonaaron.net/code/livequery/docs). It allows you to simulate the `.live()` but extends the behaviour to DOM elements, not just events.

Comment: I would like some peace of code from this plugin that would do this, without using the plugin

Answer (score 1):

Not with jQuery's live(), but you could monitor the form for changes to the DOM and trigger ajaxForm() from there. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091661/detect-element-content-changes-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use jQuery live, all you need to do is put the ajaxForm code inside a function and then in the ajax success you just call the function again to rebind the new form in the view.

```
    function bindSubmitNewPost()  {

     var options = { 
        target:        '#new-post-message-1',  
        beforeSubmit:  showRequest, 
        success:       showResponse  

       }; 


    $('.FormNewPost').ajaxForm(options);  
}
```