# How do i check if anything changed in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detect element content changes with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091661/detect-element-content-changes-with-jquery)

I have a div with a few text fields and radio buttons and text areas and i want to check if any of the content changed for example...i have

```
<div class="tools">
     //if any of the content changes in here can i find out
</div>
```

i have

```
 $('.tools').change(function(){
console.log("something changed");
});
```

and its not logging....so i need to loop or check content...any ideas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could possible do something like this.

```
$('.tools').find('input,textarea')
.each(function(){
     $(this).change(function(){
          console.log("Something changed");
     }
});
```

I did not test this, but it might help:-)

Comment: That would require form elements to be placed in this element. But what if it isn't a form?

Comment: I believe with his example he was referring to elements inside of that div tools element. If it was not inside of the tools class, you could add a class to each one of the form elements throughout the page and do the each loop on that class.

Comment: You actually don't need the each() loop since most jQuery methods are written to work with multiple elements.