# How to trigger an onChange event in HTML, even if the content is changed in js?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input, dom-events

I know the HTML `onChange` event is triggered only when the element is blurred.

But is there a way to run a script when the content of a textbox changes? Even if it is changed in Javascript?

I have a textbox in my form to select a date. I also have a button with a calendar to pick a date. This calendar writes in the textbox and I want to do something when the date changes.

I cannot change the Javascript of the calendar.

I also want compatibility with all major browsers (IE7-9, Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera, ...).

Comment: Does the calendar have an event to let you know something was selected? Well written components do.

Comment: do you have a link to a demo?

Comment: @epascarello: No, there is no such events.

Comment: @GregThompson: I'm working in localhost for now, so I don't have any url to give you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to my question wich is maybe not the better one, but still works. It uses javascript timers.

```
function watchElement()
{
    var newVal = document.FormName.TextboxName.value;
    if(oldVal != newVal) {FunctionToCall();}
    oldVal = newVal;
}

var oldVal = document.FormName.TextboxName.value;
setInterval(watchElement, 500);
```

I know this is not the better code in the world, but it works for every major browsers.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for mutation events (eg. DomAttrModified).

See [Detect element content changes with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091661/detect-element-content-changes-with-jquery) if that would help you as a starter.

Comment: I'm not sure how to use mutation events properly, can you give an example? Is it compatible with all browsers?

Comment: No, they're not cross-browser but rather "new" implementation.

However I think there are readily-made plugins / scripts to behave like mutations would behave. I've seen at least jQuery Mutation Events plugin.

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot use jQuery in my project.