# Check and process the div block after its loading

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my HTML, one div block(whose id looks like kdsm_32532535) is dynamically created after about 15-20 seconds of dom loading. I want to style this block with javascript with below code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

if($("div[id^='kdsm_']").length > 0){ 
  $(this).css({'margin':'20px','border':'1px dotted red;'});
}
  /* OR below code. None of them working :( */     
  $("div[id^='kdsm_']").css({'margin':'20px','border':'1px dotted red;'});
});
</script>
```

If I would do this in document.ready, it will not work because this div block doesn't exist on DOM ready.

How do i check continuously within interval of fraction, whether this div block is loaded or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call this method in script, that puts new block to DOM. OR use the setInterval method:

```
function applyCss(){

if($("div[id^='kdsm_']").length > 0){ 
  $(this).css({'margin':'20px','border':'1px dotted red;'});
}
  /* OR below code. None of them working :( */     
  $("div[id^='kdsm_']").css({'margin':'20px','border':'1px dotted red;'});
}

var interval = setInterval('applyCss()',2000);
```

If you want to stop this interval:

```
window.clearInterval(interval)
```

Comment: new block is placed by J2EE engine. Java script don't have control over it

Comment: I don't know J2EE but you should have an option to bind to the event, when this code is placed.

Comment: you can try also detecting DOM changes in particular subtrees using one of these methods: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091661/detect-element-content-changes-with-jquery

Comment: about css classes: you can add for each div same class like <div id="whatever_23123223" class="someclass"> in style: .someclass { margin: 20px; border: 1px dotted red;}

Answer (score 1):

You can set a common class for these dynamically created divs, so the CSS rules will be applied automatically, like that:

```
.kdsm_divs { margin:20px, border: 1px dotted red; }
```

Or you can use the .ready() method that will check for DOM state. Try this:

```
$("div[id^='kdsm_']").ready(function () {
  $("div[id^='kdsm_']").css({'margin':'20px','border':'1px dotted red;'});
});
```

Comment: Id of div is not surely .kdsm_divs.

Comment: It is not an id, it's a class you can set to all these dynamic divs.

Answer (score 0):

What about using style sheets?

You probably know the context where the divs will be placed so you can set up a style rule and let the browser apply the styles automatically.

Comment: Yes. I know sure that div is being created but, id is not automatically generated like kdsm_958952325.