# When to attach jQuery plugins in Backbone view

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, live

I am trying to figure out the best and most inexpensive way to attach jQuery plugins and some basic UI setup functions.

Currently, I can think of two ways:

1) Fire a function after rendering the view. This means that each time the view is rendered, the plugins, etc are re-attached. Could this cause memory, etc issues?

2) Somehow mimic jQuery .live() for plugins... I don't know if that's even possible

Any ideas?

Comment: Normally you'd do this sort of thing in `render`. And you don't have to redraw the whole view when only part of it changes, you can update things piecemeal.

Comment: Updating only a part wouldn't work in my case because the view template can be customized by the end users - there's no way of telling what kind of elements they put the values in.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that `jQuery.live` is deprecated and you should use `jQuery.on` instead, see: http://api.jquery.com/delegate/
Anyway you may find some interesting solutions here: [Detect element content changes with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091661/detect-element-content-changes-with-jquery)