# jqplot custom legends

Tags: javascript, charts, jqplot

I try to create legends for jqPlot but they will just show the max and min values for y slope. Just like 'Max: 16 Min:2', but I can't figure out how. E.g, I tried giving labels as

```
var labels = [{'Max':16}, {'Min':2}];
```

But nothing seems to be working. Do you know any quick method or I should create my own special renderer for this?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you please give some more information about what do want the legend to look like and what isn't working exactly ?

Answer (score 0):

ufucuk.
I had the same problem and I solved it doing the following:

```
$("#hereGoesMyMinValue").text($("#myGraphId").
children(".jqplotxaxis").children(":first").text());
//first value shown
$("#hereGoesMyMaxValue").text($("#myGraphId").
children(".jqplot-xaxis").children(":last").text());
//last value shown
```

Note that this will be done only once. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091661/detect-element-content-changes-with-jquery) explains how to sync them

By the way, you  also can do the following:

```
var title=$("#selecting_period").children(".jqplot-title").text();

var coolTitle=
 title+": Showing "+ $("#myGraphId").children(".jqplot-xaxis").
  children(":first").text()+" to "+$("#myGraphId").
   children(".jqplot-xaxis").children(":last").text();
     $("#myGraphId").children(".jqplot-title").text(coolTitle);
```