# jquery datepicker for generated html input not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dom, datepicker

I am trying to generate datepicker for jquery generated html input as below :

```
<input type="text" class="cal" />
<a href="#" id="datepicker">Show </a>
<div id="newdp"></div>
```

And the JS

```
var datePickerOptions = {
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    firstDay: 1,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".cal").datepicker(datePickerOptions);
 });
$('#datepicker').click(function(){
   var html = '';
    html += '<input type="text" class="cal" />';
    $('#newdp').html(html);
});
```

I use the `js` codes as explained in [jquery datepicker not working on dynamically created html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9640493/jquery-datepicker-not-working-on-dynamically-created-html). But in my case its not working !

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NjPC3/2/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NjPC3/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to attach the datepicker to the newly created html element

```
$('#datepicker').click(function(){
   html += '<input type="text" class="cal" />';
   $('#newdp').html(html);
   html.datepicker(); // apply the date picker
```