# checking content change on Div with Jquery

Tags: jquery, jsp

**Is there any way to determine the content of div tab is change using jQuery in a jsp.**

```
$.post("/core-web/ccepar/dele",jQuery.param({currentPageNumber: tempcurrentPage,chapterTitle:postmytesId}) ,function(data)
{

    $("#center_in").html(data);
}
```

The center_in is div id  where i am putting data it is main jsp page.

Is there is any way to compare the element of (data). I mean there is any syntax where i can compare each element of data in my main content jsp.

Comment: Hiya, can you give some code as well man! or some extra info? you can access .text inside divs and compare ether with old div but again it varies; cheerios!

Comment: please be a bit more specific with what problem are you facing in implementing this, and what have you found till now?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091661/detect-element-content-changes-with-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know jsp but jquery has the `.change` function so that anything that changes in that element will activate the event/function specified.

Comment: yes sir thanks for rep bt i have used (#----).change() function but still not working...the above <div center_in> is one div where my content are posted and rest of link are are stable.