# Check if the webpage has been modified

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on chrome extension for facebook. If you use facebook, you know that when you scroll down to the bottom of the news feed/timeline/profile it shows more posts. The extension actually adds a button beside the "like" button. So I need to check if there are more posts to add that button to.

Right now to check if the page has been modified, I use `setInterval(function(){},2000)`.
I want to run a function when the user clicks the button. But this function doesn't work if I put it outside (or even inside) setInterval() – The Koder just now edit

How can I check if the webpage has been modified WITHOUT using a loop?

Example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    window.setInterval(function(){
          $(".UIActionLinks").find(".dot").css('display','none');
          $(".UIActionLinks").find(".taheles_link").css('display','none');
          $(".miniActionList").find(".dot").css('display','none');
          $(".miniActionList").find(".taheles_link").css('display','none');
              //only this function doesn't work:
          $(".taheles_link").click(function(){
            $(".taheles_default_message").hide();
            $(".taheles_saving_message").show();
          });
               //end
          $(".like_link").after('<span class="dot"> · </span><button class="taheles_link stat_elem as_link" title="תגיד תכל&acute;ס" type="submit" name="taheles" onclick="apply_taheles()" data-ft="{&quot;tn&quot;:&quot;&gt;&quot;,&quot;type&quot;:22}"><span class="taheles_default_message">תכל&acute;ס</span><span class="taheles_saving_message">לא תכלס</span></button>');
          $(".taheles_saving_message").hide();
    }, 2000);
});
```

In the future, this extension will use AJAX, so `setInterval()` can make even more problems for me.

Comment: What do you mean by "want to run more function WHILE setInterval() is running"? I don't quite get what it is you're trying to do. Maybe an example will help us understand

Comment: I want to run a function when the user clicks the button. But this function doesn't work if I put it outside (or even inside) setInterval()

Comment: So, you mean that you have a click handler function that you connect to the buttons 'click' event but that does not fire when you click it?

Comment: Yes, I've edited the question, take a look.

Comment: In the future it will use AJAX so `setInterval()` can make more problems. What do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to get a notification when the page's DOM changes. And you want to do this without using the setInterval() function.

As your problem lies within the attaching event handlers to elements that are created after the page has loaded,  you might be interested in checking out the [jquery.live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) event attachment technique. I think it will solve your issue.

In general you want the page to throw a mutation event. There is a [mutation event spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Events-20001113/events.html#Events-MutationEvent) that might be what you're looking for. Here are some links that might be useful.

1. http://tobiasz123.wordpress.com/2009/01/19/utilizing-mutation-events-for-automatic-and-persistent-event-attaching/
2. [Detect element content changes with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091661/detect-element-content-changes-with-jquery)

Comment: Important update: everyone using mutation events should switch right now to mutation observers. See [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425209/are-dom-mutation-observers-slower-than-dom-mutation-events), [Mozilla reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/MutationObserver?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FDOM_Mutation_Observers)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval('fun()',5000);
    fun();
});
function fun()
{
    alert(11)
}
```