# How do you do something if the DOM is changed?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

How can I detect when the document changes?

I know I could do something like this:

```
var lastHTML = document.body.innerHTML;
setInterval(function() { if(document.body.innerHTML != lastHTML) { DOMupdated() } }, 500);
```

But is there an event handler I can put in place, like `onchange`?

Comment: I feel like this question gets asked once a week at least

Comment: These may be of interest - http://stackoverflow.com/q/2844565/388916 - http://stackoverflow.com/q/1091661/388916

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's the old **DOM Mutation Events**, and there's the new **DOM Mutation Observers**.

---

For a quick overview of them both (and why the newer [more complex] API is better), check out this post:

[**Detect DOM Changes with Mutation Observers**](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/02/Detect-DOM-changes-with-Mutation-Observers).

---

P.S. Don't miss the comments there...