# Can I monitor changes on an HTML DIV?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I am working on a complex web app.

In it, there is a div which gets updated.
It prints something like:

> [1/4]
> [2/4]
> [3/4]
> [4/4]

Probably some JavaScript somewhere is updating with something like:

```
div.innerHTML = "[2/4]";
```

My question is:

Can I somehow intercept/(listen to) `innerHTML` changes so that I could monitor how long they take?

I am in a position where I could inject any JavaScript and I would like to collect something like:

```
console.log("1/4 has been called at timestamp");
console.log("2/4 has been called at timestamp");
console.log("3/4 has been called at timestamp");
...
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091661/detect-element-content-changes-with-jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be able to use [Mutation Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Mutation_events) to do this if the browsers you are targeting [support them](http://help.dottoro.com/ljfvvdnm.php#additionalEvents). Here is a [**small jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/c3B96/) that should work in a browser that supports the Mutation Events. I tested this in Chrome 23

JavaScript:

```
var observable = document.getElementById('observable');

observable.addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified', function(ev) {
  console.log(ev.target.nodeValue, ev.timeStamp);
}, false);

var i = 0;

observable.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
    observable.innerHTML = ++i;
    return false;
}, false);​
```

HTML:

```
​<div id="observable">click me and look at the console</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

CSS:

```
​#observable {
    background-color:lightblue;
    height:42px;
}​
```

Comment: Thanks for that... I will try that out... if it works I will mark it the right answer :-)

Comment: It worked I also forked your jsfiddle and made it specific to my original question: http://jsfiddle.net/4aPdf/ thanks a lot