# Puppeteer: how to listen for on innerHTML change

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I have a chat app with status represented by this line:

```html
<span id='status'>Offline</span>
```

and I want Puppeteer to log every time the text within this span changes.

Say, in the beginning the status was "Offline", then it was changed to "Online", and then after some time to "Away" and so on. I want Puppeteer to capture those moments and the status (Offline>Online>Away)

What I managed to do is the following:

```js
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('https://chat.com');
const statusHandle = await page.$('span#status');
let statusText = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('#status').innerText);
let iniVal = {statusHandle,statusText };
```

at this point I have the `statusHandle` and the initial status.

Now, my understanding (as per [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46825300/wait-for-text-to-appear-when-using-puppeteer) and [2](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1724%60)) is that I need to combine the two in

```js
await page.waitForFunction(
  (iniVal) => iniVal.statusHandle.innerHTML !== iniVal.statusText, 
  { timeout: 0 }, 
  iniVal
)
```

and place it in a loop. That's the point, where I'm struggling.

First it gives a type error "TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON", which is due to the passed key value pairs not being primitives, but even when I oversimplify and just do (as per [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46825300/wait-for-text-to-appear-when-using-puppeteer)):

```js
await page.waitForFunction(
  'document.querySelector("span#status").inner‌​Text === "Online"'
)
```

it yields nothing.

To sum up: I am looking to

1. Make Puppeteer evaluate the change in `document.querySelector('#status').innerText !== statusText`
2. Return the new status value
3. Have the process run in a loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd just set a recursive function with a callback:

```js
async function monitor (selector, callback, prevValue) {
  const newVal = await page.$(selector);
  if (newVal !== prevValue) {
    callback(newVal);
  }
  /* add some delay */
  await new Promise(_ => setTimeout(_, 1000))
  /* call recursively */
  monitor (selector, callback, newVal);
}
```

```js
monitor('span#status', status => {
  // Fires whenever `status` changes
})
```

Comment: PS: Haven't tried myself but this might help too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12421491/can-i-monitor-changes-on-an-html-div

Comment: Thank you& sorry for the delay. I went (after slight modification) for a recursive function, works like  a charm. For people reading - consider implementing an autorestart after N tries, as (per my readup) there is a possibility of a memory leak, also to avoid timeout error on fetching a page (happened to me once), do the following  =>  await page.goto('http://target.url', {waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'});

Comment: how can we view changed HTML, TEXT?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than polling with recursion and `setTimeout`, better use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62365560/912946).