# On dom modification

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, css3pie

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a jQuery DOM change listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844565/is-there-a-jquery-dom-change-listener)

there is a way to have a js function loaded or to call that function every time when dom is modified? I have a html page on which I expand another panel in the same page from an action button in this way the dom is modified and my js function is not called any more :|

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091661/detect-element-content-changes-with-jquery
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844565/is-there-a-jquery-dom-change-listener

Comment: No, but you could create a custom event and fire it every time you are done modifying the DOM.

Comment: Working example to detect dom change - http://jsfiddle.net/eQErD/1/

Comment: Please look ---------------> there are several

Comment: @bhb  I use it in this way but not really working :(          <script type="text/javascript">
 $(".primary").bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
    if (window.PIE) {
        $('.primary,.secondary,input[type = "text"],.nopadd').each(function(){
            PIE.attach(this);
        });
    }
    alert("tree changed");
});
    </script>

Comment: can you please add the code to a fiddle.

Comment: @bhb  I cannot because that function use a mega library called pie.js http://css3pie.com/ :|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code

```
$("#a").bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
     if (window.PIE) {
        $(this).each(function() {
            PIE.attach(this);
        });
    }
    alert("tree changed");
});


$("#add").click(function() {
    $("#a").append("<span>hey there</span>");
});
​
```

HTML:

```
<div id="a"></div>
<button id="add">Add to Div</button>​
```

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eQErD/404/)