# link click event - Add a function to be executed after the normal page link is executed

Tags: jquery

There is an existing link on the page that updates the data on the page.
(provides the next 15 records)

```
<li>
  <a href="#statistic=general;page=4;name=" target="self" class="ABC">
    <span class="btnBg">&nbsp;</span>
    <span class="icn next">&nbsp; </span>
  </a>
</li>
```

Is there a way using JQuery or Javascript to have my JQuery function execute right after the above link is updated?

Comment: How do  you update it...?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get it done with the help of DOM change event.

Please find the link below to get correct answer on this..

[jQuery DOM change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844565/is-there-a-jquery-dom-change-listener)

[Mutation Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091661/detect-element-content-changes-with-jquery)

Or else if you know the place where the content is getting modified then you can handle your logic at that place too.

Comment: To clarify:  The above link updates the data on the page. (Provides the next 15 records) How it does is very complicated and way above my JQuery knowledge.  I believe it is JQuery that they use.  What I am looking for is the possibility to add my own function to execute immediately after the existing one completes it update. So really adding additional code to get executed.

Comment: [**Mutation events are deprecated**](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-mutationevents); do not use them.