# JQuery Check for DIV contents change

Tags: jquery, html

I want to check a DIV contents, when contents of div change so i will find that there exist a form field or not. I am trying with this code but it not responding:

```
$.fn.exists = function(){return this.length>0;}
$("div.provider_name").live("change",function(){
    if ($('input[id=checkout_provider_checkout_moneyorder]').exists)
    {
        alert('Input field exist');
    }
});
```

The input fields display dynamicaly, so that's why i wnat to check if this specific field exist.

Comment: DIV's don't have a `change` event. To tackle this, you would need to use a `mutation observer` or a high level DOM request, such as `DOMNodeInserted`.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091661/detect-element-content-changes-with-jquery

Comment: Also, why don't you `trigger` the change event when you actually change the div's content?

Comment: Exact duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1091661/104380

Comment: the div changed from outside files...@Cristy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The change event is not available on all elements - so it will not fire even if the contents of a `div` element changes.

The change event is available on form elements.

It looks like your need is to work out when a particular form element becomes available, you could check for that using an interval:

```
var checkForInputTimer;
var checkForInput = function () {
    if ($("#checkout_provider_checkout_moneyorder").length > 0) {
        window.clearInterval(checkForInputTimer);
        alert("Do your processing here");
    }
};

checkForInputTimer = window.setInterval(checkForInput, 2000);
```

In this example I am just checking for the element by id, which is the most efficient search given that ids must be unique.

You could also create a custom event, but you will have to remember to trigger the event in whatever code you are using to update the `div` element. I have created a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dbGYn/) for this:

```
$('div.provider_name').bind('contentChanged', function(event, data) {
    if ($('#checkout_provider_checkout_moneyorder').length > 0) {
        alert('Do your processing here');
    }
});
```

And wherever you update the `div`, you trigger this event:

```
$('div.provider_name').html('<input type="text" name="example" id="checkout_provider_checkout_moneyorder" value="example">')
    .triggerHandler('contentChanged');
```

Comment: sorry, can you explain it a bit more... can we apply find event there!!

Comment: It alerts the msg on page load..... but actually there is no field exist in page source.

Comment: `exists` is a method not a property.

Comment: I have updated my example to avoid using `exists` - example running on JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6m95k/

Comment: Thanks Steve, Its working but a problem.... we can't assume time limit to 2000. It may take 10 minutes or 30 minutes..mean we need a logic (like live) that when ever its happend the method execute...

Comment: The interval will keep firing every 2 seconds forever (or until the element exists). But I have added an additional way to do this using custom events too.