# Create qTip for page dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, qtip, qtip2

What would be the best way to create qTip2 on dynamic page content.. Below is the jquery for generating the page dynamic content

```
function display(view) {
    if (view == 'list') {
        $('.product-grid').attr('class', 'product-list');

        $('.product-list > div').each(function(index, element) {
            html  = '<div class="right">';
            bla bla         
            html += '  <div class="wishlist">' + $(element).find('.wishlist').html() + '</div>';
            html += '</div>';           

            $(element).html(html);
        });     

        $('.display').html('<span class="displaytext"><span class="" title="<?php echo $text_grid; ?>"></span></span>');

        $.cookie('display', 'list'); 
    } else {
        $('.product-list').attr('class', 'product-grid');

        $('.product-grid > div').each(function(index, element) {
            html = '';

            html += '<div class="name">' + $(element).find('.name').html() + '</div>';
            html += '<div class="wishlist">' + $(element).find('.wishlist').html() + '</div>';

            $(element).html(html);
        }); 

        $('.display').html('<span class="displaytext"><span class="listtext" title="<?php echo $text_list; ?>"></span>');

        $.cookie('display', 'grid');
    }
    $('span[title]').qtip(); **// I have called the qTip2 function here but it only activates for $('.display').html(); the qtip2 doesn't activate for $(element).html(html);**
}


view = $.cookie('display');

if (view) {
    display(view);
} else {
    display('grid');
}
```

I have also tried to do a callback function but am not sure exactly where it should be since am still new to Javascript. I don't want to change the javascript code, i just want to be able to create the qtip2 function so that the qTip2 for all the loaded content can be created..

Answer (score 0):

I found on large html updates, it takes time for the DOM element to update. I do believe this is your problem. The DOM isn't quite yet created when the `.qtip` function is called.

***A "proper" solution would be to hook a callback into the manipulation of the DOM and then bind the qtip at that time.***

Here is but one resource to figure out how to do this:

[Detect element content changes with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091661/detect-element-content-changes-with-jquery)

---

My "hack" was the following:

Instead of:

```
$('span[title]').qtip();
```

I did this:

```
setTimeout("$('span[title]').qtip();", 1000);
```

Use an appropriate interval for your dataset.

**NOTE:** This is a HACK. Different browsers on different computers will perform at different speeds... ;)