# Reload page if specific text value is changed

Tags: javascript

I have a page with this code:

```
<span class="cbCoreFieldsAjaxValue">
<label id="hidetodo1" style="color: #e05817;">
<strong>Click here</strong>
</label>
</span>
```

When user click (is an Ajax link), the code become this:

```
<span class="cbCoreFieldsAjaxValue" style="display: inline-block;">Yes</span>
```

I would like perform a page reload/refresh when the value is Yes. I suppose is necessary to use something like this:

```
if {
document.getElementById('hidetodo1').value="Yes";
location.reload();
}
```

but this of course don't work because my knowledge of javascript are too poor :-(

I don't have access to all html but I can make some modification if needed.

Somebody can help please ?

Thank

Comment: You can use a `body.onload` in this div to call this function. For example `<body onload="myOnloadFunc();"><label></label></body>` and other function (or reference to the same function) when the status need be changed

Comment: @dotcom22 : your question is not quite clear , how the content changes ? put that function if possible

Comment: sorry I updated my question...

Answer (score 0):

Inside `<span class="cbCoreFieldsAjaxValue">` use:

```
<label id="hidetodo1" style="color: #e05817;">
<strong>Click here</strong>
</label>
```

before click and something like:

```
<label id="hidetodo1" style="color: #e05817;">Yes</label>
```

after click.

Then:

```
if (document.getElementById('hidetodo1').innerHTML == "Yes"){
    location.reload();
}
```

(if you're using the `id="hidetodo1"` for any other purpose in your scripts, make sure this new code doesn't cause any issues because id "hidetodo1" is now staying after it is clicked.)

Comment: that the problem..I cannot edit the span itself..but I can make this: <span class="cbCoreFieldsAjaxValue"> I can include anything here</span>

Comment: @Hope4You If we are changing the content using an AJAX, do you think your if condition is gonna work. Did I miss something ?

Comment: @blunderboy Apparently dotcom22 is replacing `<span class="cbCoreFieldsAjaxValue">`'s content. Then this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement is incorrect.
The if statement is missing condition

```
if /*WHERE IS THE CONDITIONAL STATEMENT??*/
{
document.getElementById('hidetodo1').value="Yes";
location.reload();
}
```

I think what you are looking for is:

```
if (document.getElementById('hidetodo1').value=="Yes") //When the value is "Yes"
{

   location.reload();//Reload the current page
}
```

**UPD**:

According to comments,the **hidetodo1** element is a `<label>` - Label does not have a value property .

I guess you missed a **text-box** in your code. Add html code for text-box after label and use the **id** of a text box in getElementById argument.

Comment: The `hidetodo1` element is a `<label>` - it doesn't have a `value` property

Comment: @Ian The question got updated. "Yes" is not contained in a `label` anymore.

Comment: @Hope4You Either way, neither have a `value` property. And the `<span>` doesn't have that `id`. It has a specific `class` that could be targeted, but it's too unclear when they say "the code becomes this"

Comment: I updated my question. The problem is I don't have full html access. I can modify some thing. For example if is required to add a span with an Id instead to put a label I can do that..

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you should execute `window.location.reload()` inside the success handler of your XHR request. That would be the best thing to do.

But as your question says: You want to reload your page on changing content of span, Here are few points that you may like/find useful.

1. You can detect change events on specific elements only using jquery. These elements are select, input and textarea. Read more [here.](http://api.jquery.com/change/)
2. You can not detect change events on other elements in my knowledge with simple javascript or jquery.
3. Take a look at [How to identify content change of an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091661/detect-element-content-changes-with-jquery)

Once again, the best practice would be to do it (reload) in success handler.