# Is there a way to track all change to an HTML element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there a (good) way to track all changes to an HTML element ?

I tried to use javascript with jQuery but it does not work.

```
$('div.formSubmitButton input[type="submit"]').change(function(event){
                alert(event);
            });
```

Somehow a style attribute is set on a submit button but I can't find where and how it is done.

EDIT: my question was not jQuery specific

Comment: Look in your browser's document inspector?

Comment: How do you "change" a submit button ?

Comment: i want to intercept the change (triggered by js) not to see if it is changed @adeneo , what happens when you do $SubmitInput.addClass('this'); ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect element content changes with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091661/detect-element-content-changes-with-jquery)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can track changes done to a DOM element by using mutationobservers:

```
// select the target node
var target = document.querySelector('div.formSubmitButton input[type="submit"]');

// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        console.log(mutation);
    });    
});

// configuration of the observer:
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true }

// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2VwLa/

This will give you a MutationRecord object with details on what changed. More info about mutations at: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/05/dom-mutationobserver-reacting-to-dom-changes-without-killing-browser-performance/

Comment: Don't forget to unregister your observers once you got what you needed. I know its a tricky thing.

Comment: Is there a way to shim MutationObserver for IE9? It seems not to be out in IE yet.

Answer (score 0):

you can either track changes on an input field or check on submit:

```
  $('form').submit(function(event){
     alert("this gets called when form submitted here you can test differences");
  });


  $('form input[type="text"]').change(function(event){
     alert("this gets called when and text input field gets changed");
  });
```

further more you could check on keyboard input on a specific input fields:

```
  $('form input[type="text"]').keydown(function(event){
     alert("this gets called on key board input before the data is inserted in input field");
  });

  $('form input[type="text"]').keyup(function(event){
     alert("this gets called on key board input after the data is inserted in input field");
  });
```

Note : `type="text"` is only an example you probably also want your password and email fields to be included. (and select boxes if you use on change event)

Comment: I stated i am using a submit button and it is not the value that gets changed but the attributes of the element itself

Comment: these values can only be changed by javascript/jquery or element inspector in eg chrome. you can not catch these changes.. you could catch your own changes if you make an event listener which you call after every change. or you check differences on submit.

Comment: there is not much reason why you should, if the person edits the element via the inspecter he could also change the code which inspects the element.. so you should always validate your data in the back-end

Comment: I do not want to do it for security reasons(obviously) but to help me debug some js code from a dirty project

Comment: @Vinícius Moraes, can you provide some documentation ?