# Auto height on UI Dialog, if height changes dialog is no longer vertically centred

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I have the below function which loads a URL into my dialog, when that URL is opened, a function is run on document ready, that function shows or hides divs depending on a value. that in turn expands the dialog, the auto height works, but the dialog is expanding downward and is no longer centered.

so Dialog Open > URL open in dialog > show panel run > dialog expands height > dialog is no longer centered.

#### CODE TRIED TO AUTO RE CENTER

```
$.ui.dialog.prototype.options.autoReposition = true;
$(window).resize(function () {
    $(".editDialog").dialog("option", "position", "center");
    $(".ui-dialog-content:visible").each(function () {
        $(this).dialog("option", "position", $(this).dialog("option", "position"));
    });
});
$(".ui-dialog-content").resize(function () {
    $(".ui-dialog-content:visible").each(function () {
        $(this).dialog("option", "position", $(this).dialog("option", "position"));
    });
});
```

#### DIALOG CODE

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var width = $(window).width() / 2;
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

$(".editDialog").live("click", function (e) {
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        $("#dialog-edit").dialog({
            title: 'Edit',
            autoOpen: false,
            resizable: true,
            autoResize:true,
            minHeight: 'auto',
            width: width,
            modal: true,
            draggable: true,
            open: function (event, ui) {
                //Show the loading div on open.
                $("#dvLoading").show();
                //adding a callback function wich will be launched after the loading
                $(this).load(url,function(response, status, xhr) {
                    if (status == "error") {
                        var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
                        $(this).html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
                    } else $("#dvLoading").hide();
                });
            },
            close: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        });

        $("#dialog-edit").dialog('open');
        return false;
    });
```

#### URL DOCUMENT READY SHOW/HIDE DIVS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    showPanel()
});
function showPanel()
{
    var panel = $("#lstAssetTypes").val();
    panel = panel.substr(panel.indexOf(",") + 1)

    switch (panel)
    {
        case "User":
            $("#dvWKS").show();
            $("#dvNTW").hide();

            break;
        case "Network":
            $("#dvWKS").hide();
            $("#dvNTW").show();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

#### HTML for Divs called

```
 <div id="dialog-confirm" style="display: none">
    <p>
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin: 0 7px 20px 0;"></span>
        Are you sure to delete?
    </p>
</div>
<div id="dialog-edit" style="display: none">
    <div id="dvLoading" class="loading"><img src="~/Images/loading.gif"><p>Loading please wait...</p></div>
</div>
<div id="dialog-view" style="display: none">
</div>
```

Comment: And does it work if you resize the window?

Comment: window resize breaks it badly, it goes further down, waaay further, i suppose actually i dont want this to happen on window resize, i want it to re auto center when the div itsself has grown in height, if you get me?

Comment: I get you, just trying to figure out if it did anything that way. :) Something i noticed: you are calling #dialog-edit when you initialize the dialog, but after that, in the resize function, you call it on .editDialog. I suppose it doesn't matter that much because you also use .ui-dialog-content:visible, but I can't see your HTML so I don't know if calling it on .editDialog may brake it.

Comment: ive added the HTML thats used for the functions, in my code ive also removed the window resized functions, i dont need those, as its only on dialog height growth i want it to recenter

Comment: Which jquery version are you using? I put some of your stuff in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EubTC/.
Resize the result box to see that it stays centered. I know you don't need it on resize, but it is to show that it works. The function that is called by resize could be called in the showpanel function too.

Comment: 1.8.2 the showpanel function above, makes the dialogs height grow after dialog has already been launched, so i need away of detecting that growth (which autoheight does) and then recenter it. I will try put a demo together

Comment: Sorry, I see I did not save my last changes. Please check what I did, i put a timer there that changes the contents, right after that it calls the reposition function. So press test and wait three seconds:
http://jsfiddle.net/EubTC/1/

Also, I don't think there is a function that automatically detects height changes other than resizes done by users. I think you need to call the function i put in that jsFiddle after changing the contents of the dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that automatically detecting height changes is not possible, there is no event for that. Instead, you need to call the reposition code manually. Use a function like this:

```
var reposition_dialog = function() {
    $("#dialog-edit").dialog("option", "position", "center");
        $(".ui-dialog-content:visible").each(function () {
        $(this).dialog("option", "position", $(this).dialog("option", "position"));
    });
}
```

(I changed .editDialog from your code to #dialog-edit as it seemed like an error)

Just call the function when you are done changing the contents:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    showPanel()
});
function showPanel()
{
    var panel = $("#lstAssetTypes").val();
    panel = panel.substr(panel.indexOf(",") + 1)

    switch (panel)
    {
        case "User":
            $("#dvWKS").show();
            $("#dvNTW").hide();

            break;
        case "Network":
            $("#dvWKS").hide();
            $("#dvNTW").show();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    reposition_dialog();
}
```

If you really want to detect it automatically, which i would only do if for some reason you can't predict when content is going to change, take a look at this thread:
[Detect element content changes with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091661/detect-element-content-changes-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$.fn.center = function () {
    this.css("position","absolute");
    this.css("top", Math.max(0, (($(window).height() - $(this).outerHeight()) / 2) + 
                                            $(window).scrollTop()) + "px");
    this.css("left", Math.max(0, (($(window).width() - $(this).outerWidth()) / 2) + 
                                            $(window).scrollLeft()) + "px");
    return this;
}

$(dialogID).center();

// calling that function again on resize of window
$(window).resize(function(){
   $(dialogID).center();
});

// or you can either call it whenever your dialog is updated with new URL etc etc.
```