# JQUERY HTML DIV hide and show based on label value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a label , that shows dynamic values based on user actions.
For example 1 or 2.
I would like to show div element with  id="charts_div"   if the label value is "1"
I would like to hide div element, if the value is "2"
This example is simplified as possible, so I could get basic idea where i am stuck

HTML

```
<label id="label"></label>
 <div id="chart1_div" style="width:100%; height:200px"></div>
 <div id="chart2_div" style="width:100%; height:200px"></div>
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready( function() {
$('#label').bind('change', function (e) { 
if ($('#label').text() == "1")
{
$('#chart1_div').show();
$('#chart2_div').hide();

}
else if $('#label').text()=="2")
{
  $('#chart1_div').hide();
  $('#chart2_div').show();
}         
}).trigger('change');
});
```

Comment: You have a round ( bracket missing on your second if (else if). instead of binding to a change event for a label (which will never fire) why not call a function that does that check where the label is changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't bind `change` event to an element that doesn't have that kind of event. Put this change logic inside the event that is actually doing the changing of the `label`'s text.

Comment: Yup. Also look at this question & answer for additional help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091661/detect-element-content-changes-with-jquery

Comment: I am getting there.thanks for advice about Bind change, i agree.

Comment: This is I was looking for    $('mydiv').bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
    alert('changed');
     });

Answer (score 0):

As it was said, you can't bind a `change` event to a `label`. Make whatever is changing your label also change the divs being shown. Supposing it's a button, do something like this:

HTML

```
<label id="myLabel">1</label>
<button id ="myButton">Toggle between 1 and 2</button>
<div id="chart1_div" style="width:100%; height:200px">a</div>
<div id="chart2_div" style="width:100%; height:200px">b</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#myButton").click(function(){
        if ($('#myLabel').text() == '1')
        {
            $("#myLabel").text('2');
            $('#chart1_div').show();
            $('#chart2_div').hide();
        } else if ( $('#myLabel').text()=='2')
        {
            $("#myLabel").text('1');
            $('#chart1_div').hide();
            $('#chart2_div').show();
        }        
    });
});
```

Check out a live example on this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yh5ek/2/) ;)

Comment: I would like to create event On Label change, but it does not work.