# Alert if text inside span has changed

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way I can alert if the text inside has changed?

Start:

```
<span class="badge badge-cart">Shopping bag (0)</span>
```

on Click Changes to

```
<span class="badge badge-cart">Shopping bag (1)</span>
```

Therefore if the number inside the () has changed display alert

Comment: why don't you put an alert inside the click event..?

Comment: because the alert should happen ONLY if the text has changed and not just on a click, what if it doesn't apply the submit? You would display an alert even tho you are not sure if it actually submitted. basically should work as a callback

Comment: So in the click event test whether or not the quantity (or whatever other property) has changed; and then trigger an alert only if it has.

Comment: Why don't you give the span an id and bind something like this to your onclick event?  $("#mySpanID").html("originaltext"); /*stored somewhere before click*/ vs. $("#mySpanID").html("newtext"); /*compared to stored value during onclick event*/

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob that var will start with 0 and when I first click it will store 1 and so on each time i click right?

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1091661/735926).

Comment: Yes....I get slammed on this site for suggesting this, but I store values in forms as hidden inputs...then alter the value of the hidden input as necessary for your application

Comment: @bfontaine yup I have read many questions in regards before but with no luck I'm afraid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var $span = $('span.badge-cart'),
    $submit = $('input'),
    text = $span.text();

$submit.on('click', function () {
    if($span.text() !== text) {
        alert('text has changed');
        text = $span.text();
    }
});
```

Comment: the click shouldn't be on the span but to the submit button, how it is not working. Mayeb because the number is updated with ajax?

Comment: Updated my answer, you have to fix the selectors of course, but then it should work no matter how the number is updated.