# Live get number of spans inside div

Tags: jquery, wordpress

WordPress has a div `.tagchecklist` with spans (tags) inside it.
I'm trying to count these spans but I always get 0.

My code is the following:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function() {
  console.log( jQuery( '.tagchecklist > span' ).length );
})
```

The `.tagchecklist` div is updated with `spans` if I add a new tag or select it from the list, but the console always output 0. Is there any way to live-check it?

```
<div class="tagchecklist">
  <span><a id="faq_section-check-num-0" class="ntdelbutton">X</a>&nbsp;ecr</span>
  <span><a id="faq_section-check-num-1" class="ntdelbutton">X</a>&nbsp;ecrrec</span>
  <span><a id="faq_section-check-num-2" class="ntdelbutton">X</a>&nbsp;ercerce</span>
</div>

<p id="tagcloud-faq_section" class="the-tagcloud">
    <a href="#" class="tag-link-4" title="2 topics" style="font-size: 14.3pt;">Account</a>
    <a href="#" class="tag-link-2" title="4 topics" style="font-size: 22pt;">Introduction</a>
    <a href="#" class="tag-link-7" title="1 topic" style="font-size: 8pt;">Other</a>
    <a href="#" class="tag-link-3" title="2 topics" style="font-size: 14.3pt;">Pricing &amp; Billing</a>
</p>
```

Somehow I just did:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function() {
  jQuery( '#faq_section' ).on( 'click', '.tagadd, .ntdelbutton, .the-tagcloud > a', function() {
    console.log( jQuery( '.tagchecklist span' ).length );
  } )
})
```

And it works for adding a tag, but for `.ntdelbutton` and `.the-tagcloud > a` it doesn't update!

Comment: Can you give us a sample of the HTML? Should you probably exclude the `>` (direct descendant), if the spans are not necessarily children?

Comment: Are the span elements added dynamically? If so, you may be trying to count them before they are included in the DOM.

Comment: They are direct children (I'm sure), and yes, they are (spans) added dynamically to the div. See my updated question.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to add it inside the `event` like:

```js
$(":button").on("click", function() {
  $(".tagchecklist").append("<span></span");
  console.log($(".tagchecklist > span").length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tagchecklist"></div>
<input type="button" value="Add span" />
```

Answer (score 1):

@Alex's answer is the ideal place to do what you need. Otherwise, you need to watch for changes to a DOM element, which is answered here: [Detect element content changes with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091661/detect-element-content-changes-with-jquery)

Comment: Thanks. But why clicking on `.addtag` works, and clicking other elements don't? Also tried to replace `on` to `live`...

Comment: live is deprecated, on is the right way to bind events.

Comment: From jquery docs: Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on(). To ensure the elements are present and can be selected, perform event binding inside a document ready handler for elements that are in the HTML markup on the page. If new HTML is being injected into the page, select the elements and attach event handlers after the new HTML is placed into the page. Or, use delegated events to attach an event handler, as described next.

Comment: are you sure your selector is the proper parent element for your code to work?

Comment: Yes. Because `.addtag` works and other selectors not. "attach event handlers after the new HTML is placed into the page" - how can I do this?

Comment: Just tested and it appears to work: http://jsfiddle.net/pxLe23x3/ If the element with ID faq_section used in your selector is indeed the parent then it should work. Perhaps the js code generating the new DOM elements is unbinding events. Need better sample of your code to debug.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I'll be trying on wordpress stackexchange because this question seems to be related more to wordpress than jquery.