# Calculate width from auto to pixel then add by pixel in LESS CSS

Tags: html, css, less

I want to use auto width and add x pixels to it.
How can this be acheived Less file?

```
span 
{
    width:calc(auto + 100px);
}
```

I want to use auto, since I don't know the length of the text. But I know a fixed size text gets append to it at some point. I don't want the span to grow larger when this happen. Therefore, adding 100px to auto would handle it perfectly.

Comment: I don't think that's possible except *possibly* by javascript. `auto`  wouldn't be defined until the page had loaded and by then your styles have been rendered...so it's too late.

Comment: I suggest doing it with JQuery

Comment: Could you not just leave it as auto but add padding on each side? I'm curious to see what actual problem you are solving here.

Comment: You might be able to achieve something like this using `padding` on the sides of the element.. Could you show us the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You should do this with JQuery.

```
window.onload = function(){
  $('span').width($('span').width()+100px);
};
```

And the CSS code remains

```
span{
  width: auto;
}
```

EDIT: If the span content changes after the onload function is being executed, then you should execute that line whenever the content changes.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091661/detect-element-content-changes-with-jquery) you can find how to do this. Credits to @Emile

> 1- The jQuery change event is used only on user input fields because if anything else is manipulated (e.g., a div), that manipulation is coming from code. So, find where the manipulation occurs, and then add whatever you need to there.
>
> 2- But if that's not possible for any reason (you're using a complicated plugin or can't find any "callback" possibilities) then the jQuery approach I'd suggest is:
>
> a. For simple DOM manipulation, use jQuery chaining and traversing, `$("#content").html('something').end().find(whatever)....`
>
> b. If you'd like to do something else, employ jQuery's bind with custom event and triggerHandler
>
> `$("#content").html('something').triggerHandler('customAction');`
>
> `$('#content').unbind().bind('customAction', function(event, data) {
>      //Custom-action
>   });`
>
> Here's a link to jQuery trigger handler: http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @Paulie_D, this wasn't possible.
Proposed solution to handle this with Javascript would probably work, but I prefer to avoid this solution as I don't like handling the layout with Javascript instead of HTML/CSS.

The solution I used :
Use a DIV instead of a SPAN. This allowed to add another div inside it with a fixed width of 100px. This way, the parent div size to content including this 100px child div. Thus making the +100 needed.

When extra content is added, child div is used to display the extra content instead.

```
<div class="ParentDiv">
   TextWithVariableLength
   <div class = "ChildDiv"></div>
</div>
```

LESS

```
.ParentDiv
{
  width: auto;
}

.ChildDiv
{
  height:100%;
  width: 100px;
}
```