# Most efficient method of detecting/monitoring DOM changes?

Tags: javascript, dom, mutation-events, mutation-observers

I need an efficient mechanism for detecting changes to the DOM. Preferably cross-browser, but if there's any efficient means which are *not* cross browser, I can implement these with a fail-safe cross browser method.

In particular, I need to detect changes that would affect the text on a page, so any new, removed or modified elements, or changes to inner text (innerHTML) would be required.

I don't have control over the changes being made (they could be due to 3rd party javascript includes, etc), so it can't be approached from this angle - I need to "monitor" for changes somehow.

Currently I've implemented a "quick'n'dirty" method which checks `body.innerHTML.length` at intervals. This won't of course detect changes which result in the same length being returned, but in this case is "good enough" - the chances of this happening are extremely slim, and in this project, failing to detect a change won't result in lost data.

The problem with `body.innerHTML.length` is that it's expensive. It can take between 1 and 5 milliseconds on a *fast* browser, and this can bog things down a lot - I'm also dealing with a large-ish number of iframes and it all adds up. I'm pretty sure the expensiveness of doing this is because the innerHTML text is not stored statically by browsers, and needs to be calculated from the DOM every time it is read.

The types of answers I am looking for are anything from the "precise" (for example event) to the "good enough" - perhaps something as "quick'n'dirty" as the innerHTML.length method, but that executes faster.

EDIT:
I should also point out that whilst it would be "nice" to detect the precise element that has been modified, it is not an absolute necessity - just the fact that there has been *any* change would be good enough. Hopefully this broadens people's responses. I'm going to investigate Mutation Events, but I still need a fallback for IE support, so any whacky, creative, outside-of-the-square ideas would be very welcome.

Comment: Not much luck the last time this was asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/648996/how-do-i-monitor-the-dom-for-changes

Comment: Yes, I saw that, and you are right...not much luck. *However*, because I don't require 100% accuracy, and also because I don't need to pinpoint which element has changed, just that there *has been* a change, I'm hoping people come up with some creative solutions for me...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a JavaScript/jQuery DOM change listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844565/is-there-a-javascript-jquery-dom-change-listener)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events/DOMtree.html

jQuery now supports a way to attach events to existing and future elements corresponding to a selector: http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live#typefn

Another interesting find - http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/monitoring-dom-properties/

Comment: Thanks, this seems to cover all bases - DOMTree events for non-IE and `onPropertyChange` for IE. I haven't yet implemented the `onPropertyChange` event but will do - see my comments on @Gaby's post for an update of what's been done so far.

Comment: jQuery's `live()` method doesn't seem to work the best in IE, so I'm also using a standard `bind()`  (then `unbind().bind()` on any changes in case anything new has been added), but using the DOMTree events, along with `onPropertyChange`, and a setInterval fallback, seems to do the trick. `watch()` seemed like too much hassle (would have to manually add to all elements as it's not a standard event type, it's just a method), and I'm not sure that it's supported properly in various browsers, whilst the other two methods seemed to cover most bases.

Comment: FYI: "As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live()."  [from docs](http://api.jquery.com/live/#typefn)

Comment: Add'l FYI: [mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Mutation_events#Replacement:_mutation_observers) say that observing mutation events is deprecated and should be replaced with "mutation observers".  I don't know if mutation observers are at all usable yet, though.

Answer (score 36):

To bring this up to date, the DOM4 standard does away with Mutation Events and replaces them with Mutation Observers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Answer (score 8):

[Mutation events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-mutationevents) are the W3 recommendation of what you are looking for..

Not sure if they are supported all around.. (IE will most likely not support them..)

Comment: I'm now using these events - I'm still checking for `body.innerHTML.length` at set intervals, but if any of these events are triggered, I make the assumption that the periodical check is no longer required and turn it off. I'm still to investigate `onPropertyChange` and `watch()` as alternatives, and will likely implement these using a similar idea, being that if they are triggered, I can cancel any other checks - `onPropertyChange` might work in IE but not other browsers.

Comment: Mutation events are currently deprecated in favor of Mutation Observers https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the DOMNodeInserted and DOMNodeRemoved events. Acording to Quirksmode, they kind of work in most browsers, with the notable exception of IE...

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/index.html

Comment: They are two of the Mutation Event types, that were introduced in DOM level 2. A handful more event types exist..

Answer (score 1):

I have recently written a plugin that does exactly that - [jquery.initialize](https://github.com/AdamPietrasiak/jquery.initialize)

You use it the same way as `.each` function

```
$(".some-element").initialize( function(){
    $(this).css("color", "blue"); 
});
```

The difference from `.each` is - it takes your selector, in this case `.some-element` and wait for new elements with this selector in the future, if such element will be added, it will be initialized too.

In our case initialize function just change element color to blue. So if we'll add new element (no matter if with ajax or even F12 inspector or anything) like:

```
$("<div/>").addClass('some-element').appendTo("body"); //new element will have blue color!
```

Plugin will init it instantly. Also plugin makes sure one element is initialized only once. So if you add element, then `.deatch()` it from body and then add it again, it will not be initialized again.

```
$("<div/>").addClass('some-element').appendTo("body").detach()
    .appendTo(".some-container");
//initialized only once
```

Plugin is based on `MutationObserver` - it will work on IE9 and 10 with dependencies as detailed on the [readme page](https://github.com/AdamPietrasiak/jquery.initialize).

Answer (score 0):

**[jQuery Mutate](http://www.jqui.net/jquery-projects/jquery-mutate-official/)** does this too, by default it supports like `height, width, scrollHeight` etc... but it also can be extended with a little bit of extra code to add new events like see if text has changed etc...

http://www.jqui.net/jquery-projects/jquery-mutate-official/

Hope it helps