# Detect changes in the DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, mutation-events, mutation-observers

I want to execute a function when some div or input are added to the html.
Is this possible?

For example, a text input is added, then the function should be called.

Comment: Unless some third party script is adding the nodes to the DOM, this isn't necessary.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457043/most-efficient-method-of-detecting-monitoring-dom-changes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a JavaScript/jQuery DOM change listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844565/is-there-a-javascript-jquery-dom-change-listener)

Comment: @JustinJohnson if you're making a chrome extension which injects JS code, it's useful.

Comment: https://github.com/Maykonn/page-info-js

Comment: I really don't get it - it's like... eh.. requesting a hotel wake up call at their breakfast buffet... You change the DOM with JS and then want JS-events to notify you of what you just did? Sounds like an awesome code-base.

If you're just waiting for a specific css selector to load there's older methods like onload="", jquery .ready() or a manual setInterval checks that solves it without an extra 50kb blob as the "solutions" below. :P

Comment: You are assuming a scenario where just your own code will change your dom. Imagine a scenario where you are using 3rd party library a day you want to know when they change the dom. There many other use cases too, that's the reason now we have MutationObserver support in all modern browsers.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54112328/what-are-some-practical-examples-of-mutationobserver-use  and  https://eager.io/blog/three-real-world-use-cases-for-mutation-observer/

Answer (score 313, accepted):

## Ultimate approach so far, with smallest code:

*(IE11+, FF, Webkit)*

> Using [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/MutationObserver) and falling back to the deprecated
> [Mutation events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Mutation_events) if needed:
> *(Example below if only for DOM changes concerning nodes appended or removed)*

```js
var observeDOM = (function(){
  var MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver;

  return function( obj, callback ){
    if( !obj || obj.nodeType !== 1 ) return; 

    if( MutationObserver ){
      // define a new observer
      var mutationObserver = new MutationObserver(callback)

      // have the observer observe for changes in children
      mutationObserver.observe( obj, { childList:true, subtree:true })
      return mutationObserver
    }
    
    // browser support fallback
    else if( window.addEventListener ){
      obj.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', callback, false)
      obj.addEventListener('DOMNodeRemoved', callback, false)
    }
  }
})()


//------------< DEMO BELOW >----------------

// add item
var itemHTML = "<li><button>list item (click to delete)</button></li>",
    listElm = document.querySelector('ol');

document.querySelector('body > button').onclick = function(e){
  listElm.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", itemHTML);
}

// delete item
listElm.onclick = function(e){
  if( e.target.nodeName == "BUTTON" )
    e.target.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(e.target.parentNode);
}
    
// Observe a specific DOM element:
observeDOM( listElm, function(m){ 
   var addedNodes = [], removedNodes = [];

   m.forEach(record => record.addedNodes.length & addedNodes.push(...record.addedNodes))
   
   m.forEach(record => record.removedNodes.length & removedNodes.push(...record.removedNodes))

  console.clear();
  console.log('Added:', addedNodes, 'Removed:', removedNodes);
});


// Insert 3 DOM nodes at once after 3 seconds
setTimeout(function(){
   listElm.removeChild(listElm.lastElementChild);
   listElm.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", Array(4).join(itemHTML));
}, 3000);
```

```html
<button>Add Item</button>
<ol>
  <li><button>list item (click to delete)</button></li>
  <li><button>list item (click to delete)</button></li>
  <li><button>list item (click to delete)</button></li>
  <li><button>list item (click to delete)</button></li>
  <li><em>&hellip;More will be added after 3 seconds&hellip;</em></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: it seems to work pretty nicely for new DOM nodes. Can we adapt it to also handle dom node changes (at least the DOM node values/text?)

Comment: Pass the `mutations, observer` parameters to the callback function for more control.

Comment: This helped me a lot, but how do I "unbind" this? Say I want to watch for a change only once, but do this on multiple occasions? oberserveDOM = null obviously won't work...

Comment: Why would this only work for appended/removed? It looks like the mutation events cover more than that.. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events

Comment: This is a good start but failed to catch when are multiple mutations at once and so the `childList` mutation is not on `mutations[0]`. You should check every item of `mutations`.

Comment: JSHint does not like ```!obj.nodeType === 1```. It's just checking to make sure the nodeType is an element, so you can use, ```obj.nodeType !== 1```.

Comment: To "unwatch", use the `observer.disconnect();` see the documentation at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: [If you also wondered who "foo" is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13278380/1951524) ;)

Comment: Well, why writing all this manually when there are npm packages that did the same for you? (e.g. [jquery.initialize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery.initialize) mentioned in another answer below)

Comment: @DenisP - most projects don't use *jQuery*, and many are prohibit from installing 3rd-party scripts (due to various organization security or styleguide reasons). There are **plenty** of reasons why you would need to write this yourself, trust me (I'm a stranger from the internet)

Comment: Why are you programming like this (function(){ //initialize and then return the actual function is there any benefit or just the confounding factor?

Comment: @LuisMauricio - this is a standard javascript [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

Comment: But what is the point of the closure in there, does it add any value? is it good for memory or performance? Is the code more readable?

Comment: @LuisMauricio - this answer is  mix of teachings & ad-hoc code and are not meant to be copy-pasted as-is. A closure is used for the memoization of the `MutationObserver` variable. (I would say a memoization is the main use-case of a closure) and the added-value is depended how often the function is called and how cpu-intense the memoized part is. DOM changes can be of high-intensity or low, depending on the component.

Answer (score 256):

### 2015 update, new [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) is supported by modern browsers:

*Chrome 18+, Firefox 14+, IE 11+, Safari 6+*

If you need to support older ones, you may try to fall back to other approaches like the ones mentioned in this *5* (!) year old answer below. There be dragons. Enjoy :)

---

Someone else is changing the document? Because if you have full control over the changes you just need to create your own `domChanged` API - with a function or custom event - and trigger/call it everywhere you modify things.

The **DOM Level-2 has [Mutation event types](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-mutationevents)**, but older version of IE don't support it. Note that the mutation events are [deprecated in the DOM3 Events spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-mutationevents) and have a [performance penalty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events).

You can try to emulate mutation event with **`onpropertychange` in IE** (and fall back to the brute-force approach if non of them is available).

For a *full* domChange an interval could be an over-kill. Imagine that you need to store the current state of the whole document, and examine every element's every property to be the same.

Maybe if you're only interested in the elements and their order (as you mentioned in your question), a `getElementsByTagName("*")` can work. This will fire automatically if you add an element, remove an element, replace elements or change the structure of the document.

I wrote a proof of concept:

```
(function (window) {
    var last = +new Date();
    var delay = 100; // default delay

    // Manage event queue
    var stack = [];

    function callback() {
        var now = +new Date();
        if (now - last > delay) {
            for (var i = 0; i < stack.length; i++) {
                stack[i]();
            }
            last = now;
        }
    }

    // Public interface
    var onDomChange = function (fn, newdelay) {
        if (newdelay) delay = newdelay;
        stack.push(fn);
    };

    // Naive approach for compatibility
    function naive() {

        var last = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
        var lastlen = last.length;
        var timer = setTimeout(function check() {

            // get current state of the document
            var current = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
            var len = current.length;

            // if the length is different
            // it's fairly obvious
            if (len != lastlen) {
                // just make sure the loop finishes early
                last = [];
            }

            // go check every element in order
            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                if (current[i] !== last[i]) {
                    callback();
                    last = current;
                    lastlen = len;
                    break;
                }
            }

            // over, and over, and over again
            setTimeout(check, delay);

        }, delay);
    }

    //
    //  Check for mutation events support
    //

    var support = {};

    var el = document.documentElement;
    var remain = 3;

    // callback for the tests
    function decide() {
        if (support.DOMNodeInserted) {
            window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
                if (support.DOMSubtreeModified) { // for FF 3+, Chrome
                    el.addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified', callback, false);
                } else { // for FF 2, Safari, Opera 9.6+
                    el.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', callback, false);
                    el.addEventListener('DOMNodeRemoved', callback, false);
                }
            }, false);
        } else if (document.onpropertychange) { // for IE 5.5+
            document.onpropertychange = callback;
        } else { // fallback
            naive();
        }
    }

    // checks a particular event
    function test(event) {
        el.addEventListener(event, function fn() {
            support[event] = true;
            el.removeEventListener(event, fn, false);
            if (--remain === 0) decide();
        }, false);
    }

    // attach test events
    if (window.addEventListener) {
        test('DOMSubtreeModified');
        test('DOMNodeInserted');
        test('DOMNodeRemoved');
    } else {
        decide();
    }

    // do the dummy test
    var dummy = document.createElement("div");
    el.appendChild(dummy);
    el.removeChild(dummy);

    // expose
    window.onDomChange = onDomChange;
})(window);
```

Usage:

```
onDomChange(function(){ 
    alert("The Times They Are a-Changin'");
});
```

This works on IE 5.5+, FF 2+, Chrome, Safari 3+ and Opera 9.6+

Comment: cant we add a active listener(dont knw wht to say!) or something that check in interval and check the dom?

Comment: Wondering: how does jQuery live() solve this problem if they can't detect a DOM change?

Comment: @JoshStodola The bold was annoying me too. I decided to fix it.

Comment: Mutations events are deprecated. You should use MutationObserver. I've written my plugin for problems like this - https://github.com/AdamPietrasiak/jquery.initialize

Comment: How can I get jquery onClick to fire before a mutation observer, that fires when a button is clicked with a ember action? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29216434/how-to-get-a-jquery-onclick-to-fire-the-same-time-as-ember-click-and-before-muta

Comment: BTW, passing *window* to *window* in `(function(window){...}(window))` is pointless. If the intention is to get the global/window object safely, pass in *this*: `(function(window){...}(this))` since in global code, *this* always points to the global/window object.

Comment: I can't see how the *naïve* function can work. *getElementsByTagName* returns a live node list, so *last* and *current* will always contain exactly the same elements. *last* should be static (e.g. use *querySelectorAll* instead). Perhaps that section of the code hasn't been tested? Also, even if converted to a static array, if the same number of nodes is added as removed, then the *length* test will exit early when there have been changes made.

Answer (score 50):

The following example was adapted from Mozilla Hacks' [blog post](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/05/dom-mutationobserver-reacting-to-dom-changes-without-killing-browser-performance/) and is using [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

```
// Select the node that will be observed for mutations
var targetNode = document.getElementById('some-id');

// Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true };

// Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
var callback = function(mutationsList) {
    for(var mutation of mutationsList) {
        if (mutation.type == 'childList') {
            console.log('A child node has been added or removed.');
        }
        else if (mutation.type == 'attributes') {
            console.log('The ' + mutation.attributeName + ' attribute was modified.');
        }
    }
};

// Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
var observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

// Start observing the target node for configured mutations
observer.observe(targetNode, config);

// Later, you can stop observing
observer.disconnect();
```

Browser support: Chrome 18+, Firefox 14+, IE 11+, Safari 6+

Answer (score 16):

I have recently written a plugin that does exactly that - [jquery.initialize](https://github.com/AdamPietrasiak/jquery.initialize).
([NPM link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery.initialize) - different NPM/GitHub user name, same author)

You use it the same way as `.each` function

```
$(".some-element").initialize( function(){
    $(this).css("color", "blue"); 
});
```

The difference from `.each` is - it takes your selector, in this case `.some-element` and wait for new elements with this selector in the future, if such element will be added, it will be initialized too.

In our case initialize function just change element color to blue. So if we'll add new element (no matter if with ajax or even F12 inspector or anything) like:

```
$("<div/>").addClass('some-element').appendTo("body"); //new element will have blue color!
```

Plugin will init it instantly. Also plugin makes sure one element is initialized only once. So if you add element, then `.detach()` it from body and then add it again, it will not be initialized again.

```
$("<div/>").addClass('some-element').appendTo("body").detach()
    .appendTo(".some-container");
//initialized only once
```

Plugin is based on `MutationObserver` - it will work on IE9 and 10 with dependencies as detailed on the [readme page](https://github.com/AdamPietrasiak/jquery.initialize).

Comment: Please, add to npm.

Answer (score 15):

```js
MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver;

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations, observer) {
    // fired when a mutation occurs
    console.log(mutations, observer);
    // ...
});

// define what element should be observed by the observer
// and what types of mutations trigger the callback
observer.observe(document, {
  subtree: true,
  attributes: true
  //...
});
```

Complete explanations: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11546242/6569224

Comment: When I try this nothing logs to the console on any of the mutations to the DOM. I must not be doing it right.

Comment: Don't forget to `observer.disconnect()` when done using it

Answer (score 13):

or you can simply **Create your own event**, that run everywhere

```
 $("body").on("domChanged", function () {
                //dom is changed 
            });


 $(".button").click(function () {

          //do some change
          $("button").append("<span>i am the new change</span>");

          //fire event
          $("body").trigger("domChanged");

        });
```

Full example 
http://jsfiddle.net/hbmaam/Mq7NX/

Comment: this is not the same... the method described above is still valid http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Answer (score 8):

Use the [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) interface as shown in Gabriele Romanato's [blog](https://gabrieleromanato.name/jquery-detecting-new-elements-with-the-mutationobserver-object)

Chrome 18+, Firefox 14+, IE 11+, Safari 6+

```
// The node to be monitored
var target = $( "#content" )[0];

// Create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function( mutations ) {
  mutations.forEach(function( mutation ) {
    var newNodes = mutation.addedNodes; // DOM NodeList
    if( newNodes !== null ) { // If there are new nodes added
        var $nodes = $( newNodes ); // jQuery set
        $nodes.each(function() {
            var $node = $( this );
            if( $node.hasClass( "message" ) ) {
                // do something
            }
        });
    }
  });    
});

// Configuration of the observer:
var config = { 
    attributes: true, 
    childList: true, 
    characterData: true 
};

// Pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);

// Later, you can stop observing
observer.disconnect();
```

Comment: MutationObserver is native JavaScript, not jQuery.

Answer (score 5):

8 years later, here is my solution using `MutationObserver` and `RxJS`

```
observeDOMChange(document.querySelector('#dom-changes-here'))
  .subscribe(val => log('DOM-change detected'));
```

The main difference from the other approaches is to fire a `CustomEvent` when DOM changes, and listen to the event debounced to execute user logic efficiently with the following features;

- Debounce consecutive DOM changes to prevent too many executions
- Stop watching after the given time
- Removes event listeners/subscribers after stop watching DOM changes
- Useful to watch DOM change happened in a framework, e.g., Angular

```
import { fromEvent, timer} from 'rxjs';
import { debounceTime, takeUntil, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

function observeDOMChange(el, options={}) {
  options = Object.assign({debounce: 100, expires: 2000}, options);

  const observer = new MutationObserver(list =>  {
    el.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('dom-change', {detail: list}));
  });
  observer.observe(el, {attributes: false, childList: true, subtree: true });

  let pipeFn;
  if (options.expires) {
    setTimeout(_ => observer.disconnect(), options.expires);
    pipeFn = takeUntil(timer(options.expires));
  } else {
    pipeFn = tap(_ => _); 
  }

  return fromEvent(el, 'dom-change')
    .pipe(pipeFn, debounceTime(options.debounce));
}
```

[Demo at stackblitz.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-gezwzb?file=index.js)
[image]

Answer (score 4):

How about extending a jquery for this?

```
   (function () {
        var ev = new $.Event('remove'),
            orig = $.fn.remove;
        var evap = new $.Event('append'),
           origap = $.fn.append;
        $.fn.remove = function () {
            $(this).trigger(ev);
            return orig.apply(this, arguments);
        }
        $.fn.append = function () {
            $(this).trigger(evap);
            return origap.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    })();
    $(document).on('append', function (e) { /*write your logic here*/ });
    $(document).on('remove', function (e) { /*write your logic here*/ });
```

Jquery 1.9+ has built support for this(I have heard not tested).

Answer (score 2):

Found the question so updating with a solution in 2022.

We have seen different solutions which mostly involve `MutationObserver`.

If anyone wants to record the DOM changes and store them to replay after some time, they can use [rrweb](https://github.com/rrweb-io/rrweb)

Edit:

Adding example, here are the hints:

[rrweb](https://github.com/rrweb-io/rrweb) you can use via [CDN](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/rrweb@2.0.0-alpha.2/dist/rrweb-all.js) or [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rrweb)

Let's take the example of [CDN](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/rrweb@2.0.0-alpha.2/dist/rrweb-all.js) for recording the DOM changes events:

Step 1: just include following script tag in the `<HTML><head>` tag

`<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/rrweb@2.0.0-alpha.2/dist/rrweb-all.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Step 2: and add the below code in your code to capture the events generated by [rrweb](https://github.com/rrweb-io/rrweb).

```js
<script>
var events = [];
rrweb.record({
    emit(event) {
       events.push(event);
       // you can store this event anywhere and you can replay them later. ex: some JSON file, or DB
    }
});

</script>
```

This example is mostly for recording events for any web application.

To know and understand in the detail (how to record/replay), please read from [rrweb documentation](https://github.com/rrweb-io/rrweb/blob/master/guide.md).

Replayer Example:

This was for debugging, however adding here so that anyone can check replayed side as well:

[Replayer Example](https://rrwebdebug.com/play/index.html?url=https%3A%2F%2Fgist.githubusercontent.com%2FCode-Crash%2Fac5cf552ad8fe02b08866880eab9eb11%2Fraw%2Fa0f7defd88fc85554e950202422c8ee3b48fcbc2%2Fiframe-zoomed-in-issue.json&version=0.7.14&play=on)

Comment: Great. See if you can add some code snippet or example here. It would make it a even more useful answer.

Comment: Sure @esafwan, Added the example please check if it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Use TrackChanges for detect html changes.
Link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/track-changes-js

Example

```
 let button = document.querySelector('.button');

 trackChanges.addObserver('buttonObserver', () => button);
 
 trackChanges.addHandler('buttonObserver', buttonHandler);

 function buttonHandler(button) {
   console.log(`Button created: ${button}`);
 }
```