# Intercepting innerHTML and execution other command

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Is it possible to somehow intercept `element.innerHTML = msg;` in one particular location and run it:

```
$("#id").text(msg);
```

instead of `.innerHTML = msg`?

http://jsfiddle.net/j8b4zoLt/

**UPDATE:**
I've found the similar question: [how to intercept innerHTML changes in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381293/how-to-intercept-innerhtml-changes-in-javascript)
and as I understand the interception innerHTML is not possible.

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking, but the answer is yes, it's probably possible, and the answer is no, you probably don't want to do it. If you want to stop `innerHTML` if the element contains other nodes, and not just text, that sure is possible, the question is why.

Comment: How about just not using `innerHTML` in the first place unless you really need it? It looks like you're already using jQuery anyway, so just use `.text()`.

Comment: Didn't realy understand the question, but could that be what you want? `element.html('<div class="msgContent">'+msg+'</div>');`

Comment: See: http://jsfiddle.net/0motnqaa/ It is a fix of your jsfiddle code, but I don't understand how it connected with your question.

Comment: `var element = $('#msgBox').children('.msgContent');`

Comment: @OP, could you please describe to us the _actual_ issue you are facing rather than the solution that you think you want? If you do that, we might be able to propose a solution. [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score -1):

This code should work

```
insertIntoMsgBox = function(msg) {
  //...
  var element = $('.msgContent') ; 
  element.html(msg) ;
  //...
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the asker's question at all. They want to _intercept_ assignments to `.innerHTML`.

Comment: can you please explain what you want exactly, beacuse the code that i sent you it works

Comment: intercept .innerhtml ? what for ?

Comment: Apparently to pre-validate the value that was assigned to it or prevent modifying certain elements. I know, it's not a good idea, but that's what the request is for nonetheless.

Comment: @ziz194 because i cannot touch insertIntoMsgBox.