# How to alert every occurence?

Tags: javascript

I need to send an alert to the user every time the z-index equals 2. Unfortunately it only occurs onload, or ready...whatever...

heres the html

```
<div id='slides'>
   <img class='sliderImg' src='img.jpg'>
   <img class='sliderImg' src='img.jpg'>
   <img class='sliderImg' src='img.jpg'>
</div>
```

and the Javascript

```
document.ready=function(){
   var theImage=$('.sliderImg')[0];
   if(theImage.style.zIndex==2){
      alert(theImage.style.zIndex);
   }
}
```

Comment: And when do you *want* it to occur?

Comment: Take a look at this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157963/is-it-possible-to-listen-to-a-style-change-event
That might help you

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices:

1) Run a timer and call your function periodically, using setInterval or setTimeout

2) [Listen for DOM changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457043/most-efficient-method-of-detecting-monitoring-dom-changes), then run your function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) function after t time to check the z-index like this :

```
window.setInterval(function(){
   var theImage=$('.sliderImg')[0];
   if(theImage.style.zIndex==2){
      alert(theImage.style.zIndex);
   }
},10000);
```

It will be called on every 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery style :

```
document.ready = function(){
   checkZIndexOfImage(zIndex);
   window.setInterval(checkZIndexOfImage, 10000);
}

function checkZIndexOfImage(zIndex) {
   var theImage=$('.sliderImg').first(); //or $('.sliderImg').eq(0)
   var tempzIndex = theImage.style('z-index');
   tempzIndex = parseIng(zIndex);
   if (isNaN(tempzIndex)) { //Let's check z-index is number
     tempzIndex = 0;
   }
   if(tempIndex === zIndex){
      alert(tempzIndex );
   }
}
```