# Trying to replace every href on the document

Tags: javascript

i'm completely new to Javascript and I wanted to create an Greasemonkey Script that replaced "/text/othertext/" to "/text2/text3" on all the href elements of the document. That's what i came up with, and as expected, it doesn't work:

```js
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (i=0; i<links.length; i++)
 {
   var gethref = links[i].getAttribute('href');
   gethref = gethref.replace(/text\/othertext/g,'text2\/text3');
   links[i].setAttribute("href", gethref);
  }
```

Thanks in advance!

---

Edit: ok, i know why my script is not working, but i don't know if it can be fixed, i'm trying to replace elements that load after the page is completely loaded (maybe with ajax?) 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kjm6P.png

Comment: It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/2g33wv44/. Are you running your script after the DOM is loaded, e.g. in `window.onload`?

Comment: I'm trying to run it as a Greasemonkey script, i've tried to debug it by adding alert(gethref); and apparently it's not storing all the links on the page, maybe it's just firefox blocking alerts from spamming...

Comment: `link` element also uses `href` to point to resources like stylesheets, not sure what others do as well.

Comment: That's an example of what exactly i need to replace: 
`<div class="dropdown list arrow-right">
                                            <ul>
                                                <li><a href="http://bla.com/admin/e/qaa/edit/5690980/">Editar pregunta</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="http://bla.com/admin/e/qaa/delete/5690980/">Eliminar pregunta</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>`

Comment: I need to replace "http://bla.com/admin/e/qaa/.." with "http://bla.com/moderator/qaa/.."

Comment: If you put `alert(links.length)` before the loop, what does it show?

Comment: @Barmar it shows up 2 times, first one being 0, then 96

Comment: So your script is being run twice, once before the DOM is loaded, and again after. The second one should be able to make all the changes you want.

Answer (score 1):

This code works. Your code looks okay too. Perhaps you are loading the script before the document elements? Note how my elements are listed before my script:

```
<a href="before">link</a>
<a href="before">link</a>
<script>
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        var href = links[i].getAttribute('href');
        href = href.replace('before', '#');
        links[i].setAttribute('href', href);
    }
</script>
```

**Edit**, based on your comments a dirty fix to cause delay in your app before running a script is to use the `setTimeout` function. To delay five seconds for example, you might use it like this:

```
<a href="before">link</a>
<a href="before">link</a>
<script>
    setTimeout(function() {
        var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
        for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
            var href = links[i].getAttribute('href');
            href = href.replace('before', '#');
            links[i].setAttribute('href', href);
        }
    }, 5000); // < --- note the time in ms here
</script>
```

Comment: Ok, i know what i was missing, can you have a look at my edit?

Comment: @Manuestaire I believe your edit makes this problem more complex. It seems you need to listen to changes on the DOM itself, so perhaps this post can help you solve this: [Most efficient method of detecting/monitoring DOM changes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457043/most-efficient-method-of-detecting-monitoring-dom-changes)

Comment: I think that's getting out of my span, i've tried with `setInterval(function() {
  var anchors......., 2000);` and despite it continuosly runs the script, it doesn't seem to change the new elements that appear when the dropdown menu appears. Will listen at DOM changes help?

Comment: @Manuestaire If all you want is a delay after page load, use `setTimeout` method. See my edit.

Comment: If this happens after a dropdown menu appears, listening to the DOM changes may be your most efficient timing. Otherwise, you could cause unnecessary delay or worse miss the event because you used a timeout and it happened too early.

Comment: Nah, a delay won't help, the element containing the href i'm modifing (a dropdown menu) is loaded when clicking on an element. What i tried was that the script was iterating forever, but it didn't seem to work. I've had a look at http://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/ and i think that if that's the only way to go, i'll be giving up on this, i don't know where to start with Ajax...

Comment: You can add an `onclick` event to the element and try putting your logic in there

Comment: That looks terribly scaring: http://imgur.com/LzWrk9m Honestly I'm not even sure that with my knowledge i'd be able to trigger the logic on click, so i'm getting off in here. Thanks a lot for your help, at least i think I've learnt a lot of javascript with this thread! :D

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure why your code wouldn't be working.

I've put together the following snippet which might help.

```js
(function() {
  var anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a');
  for(var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
    var newHref = anchors[i].getAttribute('href').replace(/text\/othertext/g,'text2\/text3');
    anchors[i].setAttribute('href', newHref);
  }
}());
```

```css
a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <a href="text/othertext">Some link</a>
  <a href="egerg">Some other link</a>
</body>
```

If you run this snippet you'll see only one anchor is updated correctly as intended.

Hope that helps you out!

Comment: Tried with `window.onload = function(){
  var anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a');
  for(var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
    var newHref = anchors[i].getAttribute('href').replace(/admin\/e/g,'moderator');
    anchors[i].setAttribute('href', newHref);
  }
};
alert('"it runs"');`


Links still not changing, i'm willing to provide my skype to share desktop if i can get any help in that way...

Comment: Hey @Manuestaire , where is your script file being loaded into the DOM? I would personally avoid `window.onload` and use the code as I've written it inside an IIFE. (the safety wrapper function) so that it runs anyway. Make sure however that your script tag is the last element within the body after all of your links. Hope that helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to wrap your code in this:

```
window.onload = function(){
    /* your code here */
};
```

This will ensure that your code (especially if you've placed your script in the  of the document, won't load until the whole page is loaded (including text, images, etc).

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML
    .replace('<a href="text/othertext/"', '<a href="text2/text3"');
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <a href="text/othertext/">Some link</a>
  <a href="egerg">Some other link</a>
</body>
```

Comment: Tried that too, links still not changing... (i'm tinking i could stream my screan throw twitch, if anyone is interested)

Comment: @Manuestaire Please retry now (added `window.onload`).