# Adding event listener for each new element added on body

Tags: javascript

I want to do a function like `Draggable` from *interact.js*. This function adds events to multiple elements, depending of the class name, ID or tag name I choose. When a new element is added on body, it gets an event from this function from *interact.js* (that maybe like `click`,`mousedown`,`mousemove`,`mouseup`). I don't know if my way is good to do:

- add a `onchange` event to the body to check if a element was added (by the innerHTML)

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Show us what you have. We will help you from there

Comment: If you are creating dynamic elements, give that element a unique `id` and simply use `if(document.getElementById('ElementID'))` after appending to the page to check that element exists. It's hard to give a solid answer/solution without seeing the relevant source code and understand which part you're having problems with.

Comment: @NewToJS Your way sounds to be clean, but I have to make this be more faster, without performance problems. If I check if the element exists everytime, it probably will l-a-g? My code isn't ready yet, and it's very simple, for the reason I don't post it.

Comment: @Errorever if you want to know the element exists you will have to check it no matter what. You can't find out if an element has been created without checking that it exists so some form of check will be needed. that simple if condition will work just fine.

Comment: MutationObserver is probably what you'll want, assuming you don't have to support an older browser. If you post your code so far we can show you how to take advantage of it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: @NewToJS But so it will be everytime returning a longer div, imagine in each every 120 ms when the body was changed? Remind, it's very bad to use `document.getElementById...` everytime also, so you will want to make it be into some new variable, that easilize the element access, then the document will get a bad performance because of the rest of variables, a solution maybe is to put them into an array.

Comment: @Thriggle My code is very simple, man. Thanks for this link.

Comment: I didn't say use it on the change event if the body. I said use it after appending the element to confirm that element has been created 'exists'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this should help [Most efficient method of detecting/monitoring DOM changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457043/most-efficient-method-of-detecting-monitoring-dom-changes)

But everyone here appreciates a code snippet to see where you're stuck. please post it

Comment: This is completaly about jQuery? Well, I'm not using jQuery. I'm seeing something that was linked there (https://github.com/adampietrasiak/jquery.initialize/blob/master/jquery.initialize.js). Anyway I think I'll remove `interact.js` from my document, so if I put jQuery it will be the same, without performance problems. Well, thanks for the question link, so because I can't find anything out.

Comment: Agreed but pure javascript wiring is hard to come by since the cumbersome code to handle browser quirks exist. That is precisely people prefer jquery so that they can focus on logic instead of core event handling stuff