# Javascript global "creation element" listener

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

How can I add a global listener in Javascript such that I see which html element (like a div, span, etc..) is created, and can decorate them if required?

In my case I want to add an class attribute to an html "input" element, if certain conditions are met.

It's an interactive website, so elements are created dynamically, so I can't do it when the page loaded as the input elements aren't created yet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect changes in the DOM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219758/detect-changes-in-the-dom) See also [Most Efficient Method of Detecting/Monitoring Dom Changes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457043/most-efficient-method-of-detecting-monitoring-dom-changes)

Comment: You mean this api? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: I looked at it, and played with it, but I don't think it's a duplicate. I want to be informed on "every" creation of an InputElement somewhere on the DOM, while with MutationObserver I have to specify the Element that I want observe DOM mutations and it will inform me only the mutations on the Element I specify.  But I have no idea which Element to specify. If I specify the BODY, I see only a few elements that are added/removed, I am not informed about an INPUT element that is created as a Child of a Child of the BODY. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I found it: yes it's duplicate. I used the MutationObserver with the subtree option. I used the childList option but that wasn't enough.  I now get informed when any input element is created anywhere on the screen.

Answer (score 2):

> MutationObserver provides developers a way to react to changes in a
>   DOM. It is designed as a replacement for Mutation Events defined in
>   the DOM3 Events specification. ..[for more details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

## Example :

```
// select the target node
var target = document.getElementById('some-id');

// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
  mutations.forEach((mutation) => {
    console.log(mutation.type);
  });    
});

// configuration of the observer:
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };

// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);

// later, you can stop observing
observer.disconnect();
```

Comment: Should 'some-id' be the id on the <body> ? And how to add attributes to the <input> element that is created and received by the listener ?