# start js function when dom change is detected

Tags: javascript, dom

I would like to activate a js function every time part of a page is modified (such as setting a price range in a product list that updates the products but not the page)

How can I do? Thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Duplicate: [Detect changes in the DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219758/detect-changes-in-the-dom)

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844565/is-there-a-javascript-jquery-dom-change-listener, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219758/detect-changes-in-the-dom, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457043/most-efficient-method-of-detecting-monitoring-dom-changes