# Fire function on loaded elements with particular class without events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the combination of a data attribute and class name to fire a function to modify the content of the element with the particular class name.

Below function fires at $(document).ready

```
$('.accessControlled').each(function(){
        var accessLevel = parseInt($(this).attr("data-accesslevel"));
        if((user.role !== 0) && (accessLevel !== role)){
            $(this).remove();
        } else {
            $(this).removeAttr('data-accesslevel');
            $(this).removeClass('accessControlled');
        }
    });
```

Now I want to fire this function, on elements returned by ajax calls too. 
I know I can bind the functions permanently by jquery on(), live(), delegate(), etc, but which event to use and how to go about it?

Comment: There are multiple ajax calls and this is global level setting on the application. So I would like to find a way if possible, where I dont have to call the function after each ajax call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a function ajaxSuccess in jQuery which can be used to do something after all ajax calls.

```
 $(document).ajaxSuccess(function() {
                accessControl.checkAccessControl();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just execute the code above against returned code:

eg:

```
function doit(obj){
    $(obj).each( // rest of your function
}

// ...

$.get(...).done(function(data){
    var obj = $(data);
    doit(obj);
    // rest of your injection
}
```

Comment: There are multiple ajax calls and this is global level setting on the application. So I would like to find a way if possible, where I dont have to call the function after each ajax call.

Comment: You should redesign your application because it's not a good way. Therefore, you have two solutions: 1) inject some callbacks on the jQuery's methods, 2) monitor DOM changes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/648996/how-do-i-monitor-the-dom-for-changes / http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416822/dom-mutation-events-replacement/ But I recommend you rewriting your app.

Comment: Found the Solution.  $(document).ajaxSuccess(); I can call the above function doit, so I don't have to call it every-time individually.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// obviously user.role and role must be defined for this to work
function access(){
  $('.accessControlled').each(function(){
    var accessLevel = parseInt($(this).attr("data-accesslevel"));
    if((user.role !== 0) && (accessLevel !== role)){
      $(this).remove();
    }
    else{
      $(this).removeAttr('data-accesslevel');
      $(this).removeClass('accessControlled');
    }
  });
}

// assign each ajax call to a variable
var ajx1 = $.post({/*object stuff here*/});

// put the ajax variables in an Array
var ajxA = [ajx1, ajx2, ajx3, ajx4, ajx5, ajx6, ajx7];
$.each(ajxA, function(i, v){
  v.done(access);
});
```

Comment: There are multiple ajax calls and this is global level setting on the application. So I would like to find a way if possible, where I dont have to call the function after each ajax call...