# Check content inside div repeatedly and display image if found some text

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have an html structure as shown below also have AJAX API which refresh the span inside the third div asynchronously. I want to check the content of span inside `div3` repeatedly **which is added dynamically by API**. If it contains 'Hi' I want to display image inside `div3` otherwise display nothing.

```
<div id="div1">
  <div id="div2">
   <div id="div3">
       <span>Hi</span>
   </div> 
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
         $(function(){
          (function loopsiloop(){
            setTimeout(function(){
            var tmp = $('#div3').find("span").val();
            if(tmp=='hi'){
            document.getElementById("myChatLinkInfo").innerHTML ='<img src="http://slovnikonline.com/img/hi-ohio-logo.jpg">';
            }
            loopsiloop();
        },4000);
    })();
loopsiloop();
         });
</script>
```

Comment: what code do you got so far?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I monitor the DOM for changes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/648996/how-do-i-monitor-the-dom-for-changes)

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to repeat a function: `setInterval()` and `setTimout( // call fn inside itself )`.

From my experience, the 2nd way is best because if something interferes with the `setInterval` function, it won't adjust its timing correctly -- over time, you can end up with 100% browser usage (basically a frozen app) as `setInterval` attempts to catch up. See:

[setTimeout or setInterval?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729921/settimeout-or-setinterval#answer-731625)

http://www.erichynds.com/blog/a-recursive-settimeout-pattern

---

Your code would look something like this:

```
$(function(){
    (function loopsiloop(){
        setTimeout(function(){

            //AJAX below
            var tmp = $('#checkme').val();
            $('#freshme').text(tmp);
            //AJAX ABOVE

            loopsiloop();
        },4000); // <=== 4 sec delay
    })();

    loopsiloop();

}); //END document.ready
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cq55h5rb/)

---

Here are some posts for getting the basics of AJAX:

[A simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734395/form-inside-of-load-not-posting-correctly/13734466#13734466)

[More complicated example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17887098/two-post-requests-one-after-the-other-second-post-request-doesnt-get-execut/17887642#17887642)

[Populate dropdown 2 based on selection in dropdown 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16924082/dynamic-drop-down-box/16924652#16924652)

Comment: Hi gibberish, I have updated my post with the code provided by you. But its not working as per the expectation any help wold be highly appreciated.

Comment: Break the problem into steps. First, get the loop `loopsiloop` function working, exactly like in the jsfiddle, but on your site -- just using an input field, exactly like my example. Then, put that aside, and get your ajax working - on demand, using a button. So that when you press the button, the ajax fires. **See updated answer for links to super-easy AJAX examples - study them!** Third and finally, put the two together. *But get them working independently, first.*